# Git - mapping separate repositories to subdirectories in source tree

Tags: git

**TL;DR version** - I want to track active development for multiple independent applications in separate repositories, yet have all that appear *as though* it's managed under a single source tree using different names, something like the following:

```
/root                      --> REPO_1
  /app1                    --> REPO_2
  /app2                    --> REPO_3
  /lib                     --> REPO_4
```

I tried git submodules, but since they're tied to specific commits, they don't do what I need them to.  Simply cloning the repository into a subdirectory got the thumbs-down from our architect (who then suggested the submodules).  Are there any other options that give me what I want?

**Peter Jackson LotR Extended Blu-Ray version**: We are migrating from CVS to Git as part of a larger effort to automate code builds and deployments, and I'm caught in a situation where I need some guidance.

We have 40-some-odd different applications that all fall under the same umbrella, organized like so:

```
/root_src_dir
  /app1dir
    /Makefile.in
    /src1.cpp
    /src2.cpp
    ...
  /app2dir
    /Makefile.in
    /src1.cpp
    /src2.cpp
    ...
  configure.in
  /lib
    /Makefile.in
    /lib1
      /Makefile.in
      /src.cpp
      ...
    /lib2
      /Makefile.in
      /src.cpp
      ...
  Makefile.in
```

The `lib` subdirectory contains common library code used by all of the different applications.  Otherwise, the applications do not share code.  They are largely independent of each other.  They are deployed independently of each other, and the library code is independently deployed as `.so` files.  The commit history of one should not affect the commit history of another.

To build, we run `autoconf` on the `configure.in` file in the `root_src_dir`; we then create a `build` directory at the same level as `root_src_dir` and run generated `configure` script from there.  The `configure` script then creates the build directory tree and generates the appropriate Makefiles in that tree.

In short, after running `root_src_dir/configure` from the `build` directory, we get the following:

```
/build
  /app1dir
    Makefile
  /app2dir
    Makefile
  /lib
    /Makefile
    /lib1
      /Makefile
    /lib2
      /Makefile
```

The Makefile for the library subdirectory creates an `includes` subdirectory under `build` and copies all library file headers to it.

Under the current CVS configuration, everything is lumped under a single repository at `root_src_dir`.

As part of this migration, I'd like to move each application to its own separate repository for the following reasons:

1. The applications are largely independent of each other; the only code they share is in the common library code (which will be kept in its own separate repository);
2. The automated configuration management tool (which we do not own) assumes each application is kept in a separate repository;
3. Building the whole world takes a while, and isn't necessary to deploy a single application update;
4. I want to be able to track the versions of each individual application, and keeping them in separate repositories makes that easier.

However, I want to maintain the same directory structure in use now because:

1. I don't want to troll through several dozen exceptionally cryptic Makefiles to change paths and dependencies around;
2. I don't want to significantly change processes for our developers;
3. I want to keep our same naming conventions for development (the auto CM tool uses a ... *cumbersome* ... naming convention).

So, I've tried some experiments.  Right now I have something like this:

```
/STUPID_ACM_NAMING_CONVENTION_ROOT_DIR
  /configure.in
  /Makefile.in
/STUPID_ACM_NAMING_CONVENTION_APP1
  /Makefile.in
  /src.cpp
  ...
/STUPID_ACM_NAMING_CONVENTION_APP2
  /Makefile.in
  /src.cpp
  ...
/STUPID_ACM_NAMING_CONVENTION_LIB
  /Makefile.in
  /lib1
    /Makefile.in
    /src.cpp
    ...
  /lib2
    /Makefile.in
    /src.cpp
```

As a first pass, I cloned `STUPID_ACM_NAMING_CONVENTION_ROOT_DIR` to a directory named `root_src_dir`, and then under `root_src_dir` I cloned each application repository to a subdirectory using our old naming convention:

```
$ git clone $REPO_HOME/STUPID_ACM_NAMING_CONVENTION_ROOT_DIR root_src_dir
$ git clone $REPO_HOME/STUPID_ACM_NAMING_CONVENTION_APP1 root_src_dir/app1dir
$ git clone $REPO_HOME/STUPID_ACM_NAMING_CONVENCTION_APP2 root_src_dir/app2dir
$ git clone $REPO_HOME/STUPID_ACM_NAMING_CONVENTION_LIB root_src_dir/lib
```

This "worked"; I was able to build the same way I always have; even better, I wrote a script that only needed to clone the root dir, library dir, and application dir to do a build (no need to replicate the entire source tree to build a single application). I can track each application in its own repository and tag it in a meaningful way.  Pushes and pulls seem to work, haven't played much with branching and merging, but we're not going to get fancy with that anyway.  However, I was informed that this was a less-than-optimal solution since the CM group doesn't know about our directory structure, so they wouldn't be able to reproduce this without input from us (or a script).

Fair enough.  So I played with submodules.  I have seen numerous articles around the 'net warning against submodules, and now I understand why.  When you attach a submodule to the parent project, you're attaching a specific *commit*; you can update the application repository, but when you clone the parent project, those changes aren't reflected in the submodule.  It looks like submodules are great for tracking external dependencies that don't change a lot, but not great for tracking active development.

So, cloning into a subdirectory is out (architect doesn't like it), submodules are out (don't do what I need).  What other options do I have?  How can I get the benefits of using separate repos for each application while minimizing impacts on our current build process (which assumes a particular directory structure)?  We're a small group (6 developers or so), there isn't that much churn in the code, we typically don't overlap development, we don't need a bunch of different feature branches.

Comment: You can do that with submodules. http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Can you please clarify what it exactly is that submodules are not doing that you would like them to do? I think you have some false assumptions about submodules which would become clear by stating what it is that submodules don't do.

Comment: @PeterTillemans: I do work in the submodule; I push the change to the corresponding repository.  I then clone the superproject somwhere else to do a build.  My changes don't show up in that cloned project.  Re-reading on submodules to see what I did wrong.

Comment: @JohnBode your changes will show up when you commit/push the toplevel project. The sha-1 of the changed submodule will be updated in the toplevel project. According to me this is sane 'baseline' behavior. The submodules are only advanced when the toplevel is pushed, i.e. the baseline changes with the toplevel is pushed.

Comment: @PeterTillemans: Ah.  So even if I don't make a change in the parent project, I still have to push it for the submodule changes to be seen?  Hmmm.  Thing is, in this case the parent project is there strictly to maintain our current directory structure; it won't have any code associated with it (except for the very top level makefile, which isn't going to change).

Comment: @JohnBode you do make a change to the toplevel project, as it now depends on a slightly different version of the submodule. You can add code to the toplevel project too. When the top is committed this then becomes the message that everything still works with the changed module.

Comment: See https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407 for some tips to live with submodules